# How to clip and show clipped vector geometry in OpenLayers 5.3.0

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5, turfjs

I have to clip vector layer based on the main/restriction vector layer. Upon drawing, if some part of the drawn layer is outside restriction layer, clip area that is outside restriction layer.

*Example 1.
As we can see, part of the bottom border is outside restriction (purple layer)*

[image]

I'm wondering if it is possible upon adding feature to clip area that is outside restriction layer

*Example 2. Removing area that is outside restriction layer* (green color)

[image]

I tried to calculate geometry using bboxPolygon function from ([Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/docs/#bboxPolygon)) library. Even tried with booleanWithin to detect if the drawn polygon is outside restriction layer but to no avail.

Now, I'm wondering if it is possible to clip area then upon `addfeature` render clipped area within restriction layer (as shown in example 2)

Here is code snippet that I used to somehow detect if area is clipped or if is it within restriction layer.

```
// detect if drawn layers is outside restriction layer
vectorDrawLayer.getSource().on('addfeature', (evt) => {
  let feature = evt.feature;
  //let coordinatess = feature.getGeometry().clone().transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326').getCoordinates();

  let geojsonFormat = new GeoJSON();

  let firstGeometryObject = {};
  let secondGeometryObject = {};

  if (vectorDrawLayer.getSource().getState() === 'ready') {
    let firstGeometry = vectorDrawLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[0];
    let secondGeometry = restrictionLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[0];

    firstGeometryObject = geojsonFormat.writeFeatureObject(firstGeometry, { dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' });

    secondGeometryObject = geojsonFormat.writeFeatureObject(secondGeometry, { dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' });
  }

  let isWithin = booleanWithin(firstGeometryObject, secondGeometryObject)
  let clipped = bBoxclip(firstGeometryObject, transformedExtent);

  //console.log(JSON.stringify(firstGeometryObject))
  console.log(clipped.geometry.coordinates);
  console.log(isWithin);
})
```

**UPDATE:**

I was able to extract only polygon that is within restriction layer using http://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect but now I'm having problem rendering only intersected layer.

Initially, I wanted do delete layer source, then upon getting intersecting polygon coordinates I want to add new intersected polygon geometry (without outside area) but I can't render anything (seems that I'm missing something)

Here is code snippet:

```
  let geojsonFormat = new GeoJSON();
  let firstGeometryObject = {};
  let secondGeometryObject = {};
  let feature;
  if (vectorDrawLayer.getSource().getState() === 'ready') {

    let firstGeometry = vectorDrawLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[0];
    let secondGeometry = restrictionLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[0];


    firstGeometryObject = geojsonFormat.writeFeatureObject(firstGeometry, { dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' });

    secondGeometryObject = geojsonFormat.writeFeatureObject(secondGeometry, { dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' });

    let intersectTest = intersect(firstGeometryObject, secondGeometryObject);

    let polygon = new Polygon(intersectTest.geometry.coordinates)

    feature = new Feature({
      geometry: polygon,
      name: 'test BlaBla'
    });
    console.log(feature)
    vectorDrawSource.removeFeature(firstGeometry);
    vectorDrawSource.addFeatures(feature);
  }
```

Here is link to test app (update):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vpdnbf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've figure it out. Using [intersect](https://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect) function I got intersected feature object by passing transformed GeoJSON objects into functions.

Example:

```
let secondGeometryObject = secondGeometryObject = geojsonFormat.writeFeatureObject(secondGeometry, { dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' });
```

Then creating new polygon using coordinates from intersected feature object.

```
let intersectPolygon = intersect(firstGeometryObject, secondGeometryObject);

let polygon = new Polygon(intersectPolygon.geometry.coordinates)
```

Then, I transformed polygon and fetch transformed coordinates ('EPSG:4326')

```
let transformedPoly = polygon.clone().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857').getCoordinates();
```

And finally set newly fetched coordinates into event feature

```
evt.feature.getGeometry().setCoordinates(transformedPoly);
```

Or, we can use something like this:

```
// transforming polygon to epsg:3857
let transformedPoly = polygon.clone().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
// set newly transformed polygon to feature
evt.feature.setGeometry(transformedPoly);
```

Here is fixed solution:

[image]

If someone is having better idea how to clip and fetch coordinates feel free to post answer, I ll definitely upvote :) 
Hope it helps someone :)

Updated link to app is here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vpdnbf

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to render features inside a polygon you can use a crop filter on the layer. See this example https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/filter/map.filter.crop.html

Comment: Does this work with vector layers as well? Besides clipping I need clipped feature geometry as well. Nevertheless thank you for your time and effort but unfortunately I believe that this answer is not solution to my problem :)